# Как упростить код(обращение к элементу)?

Tags: javascript

Как упростить данную строку в коде ?

`const userID = Number(event.target.closest('td').previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);`

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('js--btn-delete')) {
                const userID = Number(event.target.closest('td').previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent);
                console.log(userID)
                const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
                userData.filter(item => {
                    if (userID === item.id) {
                        event.target.closest("tr").remove();
                        localStorage.removeItem(item);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

```html
            <tr>
                 <td class="userId"></td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.phone}</td>
                <td>${user.age}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn">View</button>
                    <button class="btn">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn js--btn-delete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Либо `const userID = Number(event.target.closest('tr').querySelector(".userId").textContent);`, либо же я бы добавлял атрибут `data-id` на `<tr>`, тогда можно было бы const `userID = Number(event.target.closest('tr').dataset.id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы для простоты работы добавил `data атрибут` именно на `TR` чтобы не прописывать на каждой из кнопок. строки с `localStorage` заккоментил так как они в снипете работать не будут вместо этого добавил массив, который меняю через `splice` в конечном счете массив лучше иметь в таком виде так как `localStorage` можно повредить (если пользователь может что-то поломать, он рано или поздно поломает) и его лучше ипользовать на событии перезагрузки страницы [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) сохранять, ну а потом вытягивать при загрузке.

```js
const userData = [
  {id:"1"},
  {id:"2"}
]
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if ( event.target.classList.contains('js--btn-delete')) {  
    const userID = event.target.closest('TR').dataset.id
    //const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    userData.splice(0, userData.length,
      ...userData.filter(item => userID !== item.id)
    )
    event.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userData))   
    //localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(userData));     
  }  
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-id="1" >
    <td class="userId"></td>
    <td>Иван</td>
    <td>Иванов</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn">View</button>
        <button class="btn">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn js--btn-delete">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="2">
    <td class="userId"></td>
    <td>Петр</td>
    <td>Петров</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn">View</button>
        <button class="btn">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn js--btn-delete">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```